# How do I filter an nested array of objects in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following model shows a nested struct. The struct subject has an array of units, which in turn each units has an array of outcomes. The idea is that some outcomes belong to specific unit. When I creation a navigation link and I tap unit 1 it shows the outcomes for both unit 1 and unit 2. I only want to be able to show outcomes for the unit being tap. I tried different ways for example creating a unitNumber to match the outcome with the unit, but that was unsuccessful. If I need to add or delete anything to improve the question, do not hesitate to ask.

```
struct Subject {
    let name: String
    let teacher: Teacher
    let schoolYear: String
    let unit: [Unit]
    let color: Color
    let numberOfUnits: Int
    
    struct Unit: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        let name: String
        let theme: String
        let timeFrame: Date
        let outcome: [Outcome]
        let color: Color
        let unitNumber: Int
        
        struct Outcome: Identifiable {
            var id = UUID()
            let name: String
            let description: String
            let indicators: [Indicator]
            let grade: Grade
            let unitNumber: Int
            
            struct Indicator: Identifiable {
                var id = UUID()
                let name: String
                let description: String
                let grade: Grade
            }
        }
    }
    struct Teacher {
        let name: String
        let gradeLevel: GradeLevel
        enum GradeLevel {
            case ji, si
        }
    }
}

enum Grade {
    case ny, p, hp
}
```

The views are the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var model: SubjectViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 300))], spacing: 20) { 
                    NavigationLink { 
                        ForEach(model.subject.unit) { unit in
                            ForEach(unit.outcome) { outcome in
                                OutcomeView(outcome: outcome)
                            }
                        }
                    } label: { 
                        ForEach(model.subject.unit) { unit in
                            UnitView(unit: unit)
                                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            .navigationTitle("Welcome to " + model.subject.name)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct OutcomeView: View {
    let outcome: Subject.Unit.Outcome
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) { 
            Text(outcome.name)
                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
            Text(outcome.description)
                .font(.title3.bold())
        }
    }
}

struct UnitView: View {
    let unit: Subject.Unit
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Unit \(unit.unitNumber)")
                .font(.largeTitle.bold())
            Text(unit.name)
                .font(.title3.bold())
            Text(unit.timeFrame.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))
                .font(.caption2)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .padding()
        .background(unit.color)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This is the example data

```
let example = Subject(name: "Algebra", teacher: Subject.Teacher(name: "Gerard Gomez", gradeLevel: .ji), schoolYear: "2022-2023", unit: [Subject.Unit(name: "Equations and Cell Structure", theme: "Structures", timeFrame: Date.now, outcome: [Subject.Unit.Outcome(name: "U.1.O.1", description: "Students will be able to solve equations", indicators: [Subject.Unit.Outcome.Indicator(name: "I.1.O.1", description: "Students will be able to solve two step equations", grade: .hp), Subject.Unit.Outcome.Indicator(name: "I.2.O.1", description: "Students will be able to solve one step equations", grade: .p)], grade: .hp, unitNumber: 1), Subject.Unit.Outcome(name: "U.1.O.2", description: "Students will be able to solve equations", indicators: [Subject.Unit.Outcome.Indicator(name: "I.1.O.2", description: "Students will be able to solve two step equations", grade: .hp), Subject.Unit.Outcome.Indicator(name: "I.2.O.2", description: "Students will be able to solve one step equations", grade: .p)], grade: .ny, unitNumber: 1)], color: .orange, unitNumber: 1), Subject.Unit(name: "Linear Equation and Ecosystem", theme: "Systems", timeFrame: Date.now, outcome: [Subject.Unit.Outcome(name: "U.2.O.1", description: "Students will be able to solve equations", indicators: [Subject.Unit.Outcome.Indicator(name: "I.1.O.2", description: "Students will be able to solve two step equations", grade: .hp), Subject.Unit.Outcome.Indicator(name: "I.2.O.2", description: "Students will be able to solve one step equations", grade: .p)], grade: .hp, unitNumber: 2)], color: .pink, unitNumber: 2)], color: .indigo, numberOfUnits: 2)
```

Comment: Sounds like a data storage issue vs a filtering issue. Why does Unit 1 have access to the outcomes of Unit 2

Comment: So you have one navigationLink, which is the content of the LazyVGrid - why not a ForEach as the content of the LazyVGrid, with a different navigation link for each thing?

Comment: That is a good question, however I do not know how else to structure my model to make that happen @loremipsum

Comment: I replaced the lazyVGrid with a ForEach, but now I get duplicates of unit 1 and unit 2. I will keep playing around with it. @Shadowrun

Comment: I don't think it is a structure issue, the issue is how you are loading the data. The `outcome: [Outcome]` from each `Unit` should not include the outcomes for another unit. In short I don't think this can be resolved here, the data should be there in the first place, filtering is a bandaid to a much bigger issue.

Comment: @Shadowrun, it worked with your suggestion. I had two ```ForEach(model.subject.unit)```.